# Wrong sequence assign to delivery order [ Odoo 9.0 ]

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

On sale order Confirm automatically delivery name assign to delivery order. This delivery order name has sequence wise number.

It is working properly 200-300 delivery but any time it miss random number delivery sequence like 2, 5 number skips.

So tell me if you have same issue faced or any solutions.

Comment: Please show your efforts/codes in your question. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: That's more an issue for https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues

Comment: `seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].search([('id', '=', self.picking_type_id.sequence_id.id)])`

and then took sequence from code like


`self.name = seq.next_by_id()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer of this issue.

If any warning or error raised then this next number is already increased by its allocated steps. I assign this delivery name just before return statement.